# JavaFX Rectangle to circle animation

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a rectangular pane that I'm using as a banner to hold icons vertically across the stage of my application for my home screen. Currently when I click on the icon I use a transition to slide the pane up (off screen), create a circle shape under the icon, and then move the icon and the circle together to the top right corner. Clicking on the icon in the corner reverses the animation and brings me back to my home screen.

Instead of sliding my pane up I'd like to have my pane transform into this circle shape at where the Icon is.

I don't mind setting my pane to be transparent and creating a rectangle shape and then transform this rectangle to the circle - I think this is more doable.

I haven't been able to find any clear example of transforming one shape to another though. I found this pretty good example, but it is for iOS: [Circle to rectangle transformation animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032410/circle-to-rectangle-transformation-animation)

Any suggestions? I really only need a small example animation of turning a rectangle shape to a circle shape.

Thanks!

Comment: `"you want both the scaling up and corner radius reduction to happen at the same time"` Citated from the post you provided. So what is the exact problem? You figured out animations in javafx in general, you know what to properties to modify, are there more requirements to get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider animating the clip of a region. You can combine this with a translation to move the "menu" to the top right. Here is a simple example:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatingIconMenu extends Application {

    private BorderPane root ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox menu = new HBox(10);
        BorderPane.setMargin(menu, new Insets(10));
        menu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4 ; i++) {
            Option opt = new Option("Choice "+i);
            opt.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {

                Node view = opt.getView();
                Bounds b = view.getBoundsInParent();

                Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
                Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
                Duration duration = Duration.seconds(0.66);

                if (isNowSelected) {

                    clip.setWidth(menu.getWidth());
                    clip.setHeight(menu.getHeight());

                    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(duration, 
                        new KeyValue(clip.xProperty(), b.getMinX()),
                        new KeyValue(clip.yProperty(), b.getMinY()),
                        new KeyValue(clip.widthProperty(), b.getWidth()),
                        new KeyValue(clip.heightProperty(), b.getHeight()), 
                        new KeyValue(clip.arcWidthProperty(), Math.min(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight())),
                        new KeyValue(clip.arcHeightProperty(), Math.min(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight())),
                        new KeyValue(menu.translateXProperty(), menu.getWidth() - b.getMaxX())));

                    timeline.setOnFinished(e -> showPage(opt));

                } else {

                    clip.setWidth(b.getWidth());
                    clip.setHeight(b.getHeight());
                    clip.setX(b.getMinX());
                    clip.setY(b.getMinY());
                    clip.setArcWidth(Math.min(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()));
                    clip.setArcHeight(Math.min(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()));

                    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(duration,
                        new KeyValue(clip.xProperty(), 0),
                        new KeyValue(clip.yProperty(), 0),
                        new KeyValue(clip.widthProperty(), menu.getWidth()),
                        new KeyValue(clip.heightProperty(), menu.getHeight()),
                        new KeyValue(clip.arcHeightProperty(), 0),
                        new KeyValue(clip.arcWidthProperty(), 0),
                        new KeyValue(menu.translateXProperty(), 0)));

                    timeline.setOnFinished(e -> showHome());
                }
                menu.setClip(clip);

                timeline.play();
            });
            menu.getChildren().add(opt.getView());
        }

        root = new BorderPane();
        showHome();
        root.setTop(menu);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void showPage(Option option) {

        Label label = new Label(option.getOptionText());
        label.setFont(Font.font("sans-serif", FontWeight.BOLD, 48));
        root.setCenter(label);
    }

    private void showHome() {
        Label label = new Label("Home");
        label.setFont(Font.font("sans-serif", FontWeight.BOLD, 48));
        root.setCenter(label);
    }

    public static class Option {

        private BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        private final String optionText ;
        private final Label view ;

        public Option(String optionText) {
            this.optionText = optionText ;
            this.view = new Label(optionText);
            view.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            view.setWrapText(true);
            view.setPrefSize(80, 80);
            view.setStyle("-fx-background-color: -fx-background; -fx-background: "+randomColor()+";"); 
            view.setOnMouseClicked(e -> setSelected(!isSelected()));
        }

        public Node getView() {
            return view ;
        }

        public String getOptionText() {
            return optionText ;
        }

        private String randomColor() {
            Random rng = new Random();
            int r = rng.nextInt(256);
            int g = rng.nextInt(256);
            int b = rng.nextInt(256);
            return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
        }

        public final BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
            return this.selected;
        }


        public final boolean isSelected() {
            return this.selectedProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setSelected(final boolean selected) {
            this.selectedProperty().set(selected);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```